# Phonegap build for iOS 13 SDK

Tags: ios, phonegap-build, ipa

I am using phonegap build to build IPA and APK.
When i am trying to upload my IPA in app-store. I am getting this warning

> WARNING :"This app was built with the iOS 12.1 SDK. Starting April 2020 all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later, included in Xcode 11 or later."

I appreciate any solution.
thanks

Comment: which xcode you are using to build you app. @21PurviG

Comment: I have the same issue. ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 12.1 SDK. Starting April 2020, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later, included in Xcode 11 or later.

Comment: This requires Cordova iOS 5.1.1. On the Adobe PGB community forum, the insiders seem to think that Adobe will not update PGB (https://community.adobe.com/t5/phonegap/ios-13-sdk-for-phonegap-build/td-p/10816613). Time to move off PGB?

Comment: I hope Phonegap will provide an upgrade soon or at least announce if they will continue or not. It won't be easy but seems there is no other solution but purchasing a mac and moving to local build =\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local build. If you don't have mac, you can use macincloud.

Comment: It very much looks like Adobe have dropped all support for PhoneGap Build and that anyone still using it urgently needs to migrate, as per this answer. Given the noise in the community thread mentioned in a separate comment, it seems clear Adobe doesn't care and that you are on your own!

Comment: As PGB is no longer to be maintained thus we chose to migrate and yes we are using macincloud.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively use https://monaca.io/ Monaca iOS Release Builds supported by App Store, as it uses SDK 13.
Also, Another solution is if not have mac is VirtualBox+MacOS and create a local build using Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap project is discontinued.
You can use **VoltBuilder** for compile your app like phonegap built.
https://volt.build/